# How get the line with the max date?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like:

```
|serialnumber|     location     |    medium |address|    date      | value
| 320921     | Pomieszczenie C  | Gaz       |  9    | 2019-12-14   | 547
| 320921     | Pomieszczenie C  | Gaz       |  9    | 2019-12-16   | 626
| 374836     | Pomieszczenie B  | Wodomierz |  5    | 2019-12-28   | 1728
| 374836     | Pomieszczenie B  | Wodomierz |  5    | 2020-01-01   | 1998
```

I want to get the rows with max date, based on a group by serialNumber, result like this:

```
|serialnumber|     location     |    medium |address|    date      | value
| 320921     | Pomieszczenie C  | Gaz       |  9    | 2019-12-16   | 626
| 374836     | Pomieszczenie B  | Wodomierz |  5    | 2020-01-01   | 1998
```

Could you please share your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From your sample data it seems that you want the row with the latest date for each combination of `serialnumber` and `location`.
You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where serialnumber = t.serialnumber and location = t.location and date > t.date
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4dxaUe3QdHxMPsuw2jU97/0).
Results:

```
| serialnumber | location        | medium    | address | date                | value |
| ------------ | --------------- | --------- | ------- | ------------------- | ----- |
| 320921       | Pomieszczenie C | Gaz       | 9       | 2019-12-16 00:00:00 | 626   |
| 374836       | Pomieszczenie B | Wodomierz | 5       | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 1998  |
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a correlated subquery for filtering (along with an index on `(serialnumber, date)` for performance):

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.date = (
    select max(t1.date)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.serial_number = t.serial_number
)
```

Depending on the size and distribution of your dataset, you might want to consider a join with an aggregate query:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
    select serial_number, max(date) max_date
    from mytable
    group by serial_number
) t1
    on  t1.serial_number = t.serial_number
    and t1.max_date = t.date
```

Comment: The first answer given here is slow due to doing multiple full table scans.  The second is much more efficient.  It needs `INDEX(serial_number, date)`.